# Eclipse Oxygen.3: Issues when cloning a repository

Tags: php, eclipse

How can I resolve the following issue?

[image: Clone git repository issue]

Comment: What is the URL of the Git repository (the URL is certainly not a Google search request)? What do you see when you open the Bitbucket URL in a web browser?

Comment: GitRepository url https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/techtroops/thinkcerti.git

Comment: I guess the correct URL in your case is e. g. `https://bitbucket.org/techtroops/thinkcerti.git` (see the [overview page of your project](https://bitbucket.org/techtroops/thinkcerti) for the correct URL).

Comment: Thanks,This is Helpful

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the correct URL and not an URL that just redirects to the repository URL. In your case, it is probably

```
https://bitbucket.org/techtroops/thinkcerti.git
```

(`https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repository>.git`).

URLs for other protocols (e.g. SSH) see the overview page of the project: `https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repository>`.